# Session not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Session Not working In codeigniter

Display Below error in my screen

[image]

Our Config code

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Have you loaded session library in autoload.php ?

Comment: Yes, Just like this : $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','email','session');

Comment: remove line `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;`  or set to real server path

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this setting

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

If you want to use `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';` then you need

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'the/absolute/path_to_your/session_files';
```

For instance, if you want those files to be in a folder named "sessions" that is at the same level as CodeIgniter's `index.php` file use this.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'sessions/';
```

The constant `FCPATH` is absolute path to the folder where CI's `index.php` is located. Typically, this is also the root folder for public html files. `FCPATH` could look something like `/var/www/yoursitename/` on linux or `C:\Users\YourName\Documents\www\yoursitename\` on Windows.

It is considered good security policy to put the session folder outside the "public" html files. In other words, a directory above `FCPATH`. In this case the "sessions" folder is at the same level as your public html files. The config would then be this.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = substr(FCPATH, 0, strpos(FCPATH, 'www/'))."sessions/");
```

Note that the `'www/'` above needs to be the same as the name of your public  (root) html folder.

Also, where ever the file is the permissions for writing to that folder need to be set correctly. Consult the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).