# Unable to set session in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to set using:

```
<?php

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

// header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Now, on running first time, I get:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1493663090
        )

)
```

On running second time, I got the same output. It means the session array gets empty, everytime I run my script. Why is it so?

Comment: Running command line or  in browser and are you accepting cookies?

Comment: You might try using `session_write_close()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to explicitly force the session data to be stored.

Comment: Using sublime build system, I think it uses command line. How to accept cookies?

Comment: I am using sublime text editor. It uses command line option, not browser one. from command line I am getting the same result.

Comment: @JeremyHarris tried `session_write_close` but no luck.

Comment: You can't use cookies from the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578595/is-it-possible-to-read-cookie-session-value-while-executing-php5-script-through

Comment: Sessions are going to be used in a web application and a web application will be accessed via a web browser which normally accepts cookies.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for the answer. It works fine.